# Using cte with update in db2

Tags: db2, common-table-expression

I have set of queries which are getting repeated in update query for db2
I need to get rid of these getting repeated
So what best I can do. Cte is not working in update query in db2.

Not able to find solution. For select query cte is working but not for update

Answer (score 0):

You may use so called "SELECT from data-change-[table-reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clause-table-reference)" Db2 functionality using CTE.

```
CREATE TABLE MYTAB (ID INT, DATA INT);

INSERT INTO MYTAB (ID, DATA) VALUES (1, NULL);

WITH 
  UPD (ID, DATA) AS (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2))
SELECT COUNT (1)
FROM NEW TABLE 
(
  UPDATE MYTAB T
  SET DATA = U.DATA
  FROM UPD U
  WHERE T.ID = U.ID
);

SELECT * FROM MYTAB;
```

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B5ITmWFT)